# How to delete the multiple rows based on checkbox conditon

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

I am new to node.js. I am created small example, now I want to delete multiple rows based on checkbox condition. I have one table of checkboxes as last column. I want delete checked checkbox rows when click on button.

**Jade code is**

```
<section class="get">
<h3>Get Data</h3>
<a href="/get-data">LOAD DATA</a>
<div>
    <table>

    {{# each items }}
        <article class="item">
            <tr>
            <td>{{ this.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ this.content }}</td>
            <td>{{ this.author }}</td>
            <td>{{ this._id }}</td>
           <form action="/check" method="post">
           <td><input type="checkbox" id="chk" name="chk" ></td>

        </article>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
    <button>check</button>
           </form>
    </table>
</td>
</section>
```

**Back end code is**

```
router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
    var resultArray = [];

    mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        var cursor = db.collection('user-data').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(doc, err) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            resultArray.push(doc);
        }, function() {
            db.close();
            res.render('index', {items: resultArray});
        });
    });
});`


router.post('/check', function(req, res, next) {
// var id = req.body.id;
    console.log("check value");
    console.log(req.body.chk);
    req.body.chk=Boolean(req.body.chk);
    for(i=0; i<req.body.chk;i++){
        if(req.body.chk==true){
            res.redirect('/');
        }
        else{
            res.send("checkbox is not checked");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And whats your problem?

Comment: I have 10 rows with last column has checkbox .three checkbox values are true based on that three checkboxes values i want to delte that three rows

Comment: Well what have you tried, what error are you getting? We are not going to do your work for you.

Comment: i tried same as above code but error is not deleting the rows